# Implementing a reference counter with a limit of 3 pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr, nullptr

**Update added main and cat

Hello all i am creating a sharedpointer class that has a reference counter.

What im trying to do is when i create a new object and give it value i can do so until i reach a cap of 3.

If i create anymore objects they will get NULL if i try to use obj.getPointer().

Currently when i try and create objects i get 0x22bd730 when i console log my main :(

Comment: You can use the ready made [std::weak_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) in combination with the [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Comment: Please fix your indentation

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this? What's the use case?

Comment: This is for self practice to construct templates , classes and see how pointers can be shared.

This is just for my personal education

Comment: in the assignment operator `*this = NULL;` seems an odd choice. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: it was me guessing my forward because naything i seemed to try resulted in still the pointer being there so i was just guessing what the cause was

Answer (score 2):

If you want to restrict to 3 references, your copy constructor and assignment should correctly act once limit is reached, something like:

```
sharedPTR(const sharedPTR<T>& ref) : myData(nullptr), myRef(nullptr)
{
    if (ref.myRef &&  ref.myRef->getCount() < 3) {
        myData = ref.myData;
        myRef = ref.myRef;
        myRef->AddRef();
    }
}

sharedPTR<T>& operator = (const sharedPTR<T>& ref)
{
    if (this == &ref) {
        return *this;
    }
    if (myRef && myRef->Release() == 0)
    {
        delete myData;
        delete myRef;
    }
    myData = nullptr;
    myRef = nullptr;
    if (ref.myRef && ref.myRef->getCount() < 3) {
        myData = ref.myData;
        myRef = ref.myRef;
        myRef->AddRef();
    }
    return *this;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/plgTMe)

Comment: i added the main.cpp and cat.cpp that i used , but it still shows up as pointer